# distance between section and tabular

Tags: tables, sectioning, margins

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\section*{Practical experiences}
\begin{longtable}{p{2.4cm}p{12.8cm}}
10/13-today & \textbf{Software developer}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Now the distance between the section (headline) and the tabular (data) is more than one line, which is far too big. How can I get it down to a fraction, let's say, 20% of that, or about a quarter of a line?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please complete your code (see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) in order to avoid the set-up phase for the users willing to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spacing before and after a `longtable` are configured by the registers `\LTpre` and `\LTpost`. Both are set to `\bigskipamount` by default.

The following example sets `\LTpre`, the space before` to zero:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
  \section*{Practical experiences}
  \setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}
  \begin{longtable}{p{2.4cm}p{12.8cm}}
  10/13-today & \textbf{Software developer}\\
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]